# CSS position: absolute; and inset: 0; has zero effect on image element

Tags: css

Please see this minimum example:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?coffee">
</div>
```

I thought the image should fill the entire parent box, but the image is overflow, why is this happening?

Comment: width:100% and height:100% are needed for images

Comment: Thanks.
But why the inset 0 tricks don't work?

Comment: check the duplicate